# How can I format a proper json output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the output I want to have:

```
{"USD_PHP":{"val":53.367014}}
```

Currently I'm experimenting this on a single file that contains:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'

class RemoteGem
    include HTTParty

    base_uri "free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=USD_PHP&compact=y"

    attr_accessor :id, :val

    def initialize(val)
      self.id = id
      self.val = val

    end

    # Returns the exchange rate for this particular RemoteGem
    def versions
      response = self.class.get("/USD_PHP/#{id}.json")
      if response.success?
        response
      else
        raise response.response
      end
    end

   # Find a particular exchange rate, based on its name
    def self.find(id)
      response = get("/USDT_PHP/#{id}.json")
      if response.success?
        self.new(response["id"])
      else
        # this just raises the net/http response that was raised
        raise response.response
      end
    end
  end

httparty = RemoteGem.find("val")
puts httparty.versions
```

So far when running the file I always get this output:

```
    {"USD_PHP":{"id":"USD_PHP","val":53.367014,"to":"PHP","fr":"USD"}}}
```

As you can see, I tried formatting it upon "initialize" and I know my logic and syntax are wrong.

Comment: Can you try doing `response["USD_PHP"].except(:id, :to, :fr)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem like there is a lot of code duplication.
This one version should work:

```ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'

class RemoteGem
  include HTTParty

  base_uri "free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=USD_PHP&compact=y"

  attr_accessor :id, :val

  def initialize(val)
    self.id = id
    self.val = val
  end

    # Find a particular exchange rate, based on its name
  def self.find(id)
    self.new(id).format_output
  end

  def format_output
    output_key = 'USD_PHP'
    usd_hash = versions.fetch('results').fetch(output_key)
    {
      output_key => usd_hash.select { |k, v| k == 'val' }
    }
  end

  private

  # Returns the exchange rate for this particular RemoteGem
  def versions
    response = self.class.get("/USD_PHP/#{id}.json")
    if response.success?
      response
    else
      raise response.response
    end
  end
end

puts RemoteGem.find("val")
```

Basically I've removed here duplications and added `format_output` method.
Which now returns `{"USD_PHP":{"val":53.367014}}`.

You can try it online as well: https://repl.it/repls/StarkSweetArray